# Flying in Europe without documents

Tags: air-travel, schengen, paperwork, lost-documents

A friend of mine has the following problem. 
She booked a flight from Finland to Denmark she discovered now (she is supposed to fly tomorrow) that her passport is expired and for some reasons she does not have her ID card with her. She only have a driving licence. 
Is it still possible for her to take the flight?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest she carries the passport even if it is expired. In the event of running into a border guard even an expired passport is strong (though not absolute) evidence of citizenship.

Comment: @PeterGreen Any ID at all and they'll able to check it eletronically

Comment: @Coke as I believe you are aware, some EU countries even have explicit legal provision to accept recently expired documents from other EU countries, though the details will vary depending on the countries.  The more difficult problem will be the airline.

Comment: @phoog AFAIK only Ryanair, easyjet and Wizz require ID within Schengen. "Mainstream" airlines never do except at bag drop, and in Northern Europe, a DL will virtually always do (even the Swedish Police recommended a guy not to buy an emergency passport to fly to the Netherlands, as he had a Swedish DL)

Comment: @Coke interesting.  An EU DL is acceptable in the Netherlands except for certain purposes (https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/paspoort-en-identiteitskaart/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welke-identiteitsbewijzen-kan-ik-mij-identificeren), of which the only relevant one is in-country immigration inspection, but I doubt the Swedish officer was familiar with the details of the Dutch *identificatieplicht.*  It rather underscores the complaint that the low-cost carriers have no legal basis for their insistence on verifying passengers' immigration status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On flights within Nordic countries (and most often in general within the Schengen Area), if she checks in online and only has hand luggage, she'll only need the boarding pass.

If she has to check a bag, her driving licence will do.

So yes, she can fly.

Comment: See also https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm?cookies=disabled